# How can I create an nginx reverse proxy that passes through all traffic for all domains?

Tags: nginx

I want to make it possible to pass *all* traffic regardless of hostname or domain through the nginx server.

I either want to be able to do something like this: `http://mynginx/domain.I.want.somehost/url/params/this/host`. And then have nginx forward the request to `http://domain.I.want.somehost/url/params/this/host`.

Or make it possible to hit the server and specify a host header. So a request to `http://mynginx/url/params/this/host` with HOST header set to `domain.I.want.somehost` would forward traffic to `http://domain.I.want.somehost/url/params/this/host`.

I'm having a hard time finding examples of how to do this.

Before doing any URL rewriting I tried to just pass all traffic through like this:

```
server {
     listen  80 default_server;
     listen  443 default_server;

        location / {
           proxy_pass https://$http_host;
           proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        }

}
```

When I run `curl --header 'Host: api.ipify.org' 127.0.0.1` I get a 502 bad gateway error.

This endpoint is accessible though: `curl 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json'`

Comment: you need to specify the target as a native ip and send the domain as a extra Header usually

Comment: Are there any examples of a complete configuration that does what I'm trying to do? I could not find any examples for proxying all traffic and making it possible to dynamically specify the downstream host.

Comment: `proxy_pass $scheme://$host$request_uri`